# How to set a Property of a subclass as the primary key using fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

This is my **model**:

```
  public class RepoDocument
  {
    public DocumentRecord Document { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
  }
```

This is the sub class definition:

```
public class DocumentRecord
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... Other fields here...
}
```

**What I need**

I want to have `Id` as my primary key for the `RepoDocument` model.

I am using this code in my db context:

```
  public class DocumentsContext : DbContext
  {
    public DocumentsContext()
        : base("name=DbConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<RepoDocument> DocumentsTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RepoDocument>().HasKey<Guid>(c => c.Document.Id);
    }
  }
```

**The problem**

However, I am getting the following error when I run `add-migration` in the *Package Manager Console*:

> The properties expression 'c => c.Document.Id' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

**Question**

How can I set the property of a sub-class of my model as the primary key of the database **using fluent API**?

Comment: That's not how you define a subclass.  As you have defined it, a RepoDocument has a DocumentRecord.  If you mean that a RepoDocument IS a DocumentRecord, instead of declaring the DocumentRecord as a member, you should include DocumentRecord as the superclass in your declaration of RepoDocument: `public class RepoDocument : DocumentRecord`

Comment: @JerryFederspiel I think it's just an invalid naming. Sub-class as class which is used inside another :)

Comment: yes by sub-class I meant a Class as a property of another class.

Comment: @AliSharabiani, nevertheless, you should't use terms in incorrect way. `Subclass` is a stable naming for inheritance relation, not aggregation.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is incorrect. You should be using inheritance.

```
public abstract class RepoDocument
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class Document : RepoDocument
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... Other fields here...
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RepoDocument>().ToTable("RepoDocument");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().ToTable("DocumentRecord");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you cannot, if your sub-class (btw, I've read sub-class as descendant first time) is used as entity - it will be stored in separate table, but your `RepoDocument` will have no key in that case.

I'm not sure, if it's possible, if you will register `DocumentRecord` as `ComplexType`, but you could try. it will be stored in the same table in that case, so sounds possible.

You could create separate type for configuration, then add it inside `OnModelCreating`.

```
public class DocumentRecordConfiguration: ComplexTypeConfiguration<DocumentRecord> 
{
    public DocumentRecordConfiguration()
    {
         /* use fluent api here */
    }
}
```